# Call methods of the same component with Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a vue component with 2 methods, `deleteActivitat` calls an axios.get method and then, this calls the other vue method `reloadActivitats`:

```
methods: {
  reloadActivitats: function () {
    this.$store.dispatch(actionTypes.FETCH_ACTIVITATS)
  },
  deleteActivitat: (activitat) => {
    crud.delete(activitat).then((response) => {
      this.reloadActivitats() // calls reloadActivitats method
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
}
```

But when I run the application the `reloadActivitats` method is not executed and the console shows the next error:

```
TypeError: _this.reloadActivitats is not a function
```

[Image with the vue error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQi7a.png)

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using an arrow function, you need to change the usage to a `function`

```
deleteActivitat: function(activitat) {
  crud.delete(activitat).then((response) => {
    this.reloadActivitats() // calls reloadActivitats method
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

This is because arrow functions [do not bind the value of `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this). `this` has to be bound to the vue instance for `this.functionName()` to work.

You can also use `deleteActivitat()` syntax as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions#Description).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use arrow function for the `deleteActivitat`.

The arrow function is bound to the parent context, and not the Vue instance.

Try

```
deleteActivitat: function (activitat) {
```

demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/vnm40qkzz5?expanddevtools=1&module=%2FApp.vue (Open the console)

Answer (score 0):

Avoid to use arrow functions in methods object member.

```
deleteActivitat (activitat) {
    crud.delete(activitat).then((response) => {
      this.reloadActivitats() // calls reloadActivitats method
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```